# html video file not playing

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video

Added a video (on system) to the HTML file.

```
<! doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<p><h3> Intro to J2ee </h3></p>
<br/>
<br/>
<video height="346" width="640" controls>
<source src="C:/Users/Videos/Intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Get an error `this file type is not supported` in all browsers.

Then as a trial, embedded location of a random video from YouTube. Still get the same error.

On searching for answers here, realized that "ISS manager" was not enabled. Enabled IIS manager.

I still get the same error.

A few queries on the same topic do exist here, but none of them have a conclusive solution.

What more do I need to do to get the video playing?

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted your code it's difficult to diagnose the issue, but [here is a CodePen](https://codepen.io/hanifmrwt/pen/YGEBkj) that uses the HTML5 video player. If you're not trying to do anything fancy, your code should look similar to the code in there. Compare the code in that CodePen to your code and see if there are any differences.

This is the code:

```
<video width="700px" controls>
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: My code is precisely similar except that I have added 'height' attribute too to it . Yet it does not play.

Comment: @tech_logman If you add your exact code (or better yet, put it into a CodePen of your own) we'll be in a much better position to assist you.

Comment: @tech_logman One difference I can see is that your `source` tag is not closed. It needs a `/` before the `>`

Comment: my video loads but does not play and I see an error msg "type not supported" ...did close the 'source' tag and played again but no go ..